# How to assign public IP's to docker conteiners?

Tags: docker

I want to run 5 docker cointeiners with same app, it uses port 50505, I want expose this port to internet.

My server runs Ubuntu 18.04

Assigned IPs

204.12.240.210-214

So looks like i got 4 IP adresses

I can ssh to any of them and it works.

Now I am bit fresh with docker still learning it.

Anyone could give commands how to create network with this IP and then how to start instance with this IP's ?

I believe its possible.

Normalli I start app like this:

docker run -d -P --net=host -v /mnt/chaindata:/go-matrix/chaindata --name matrix --restart always disarmm/matrix

But when u start 2nd instance it will crash cuz ports are used by first one

So I could fix that with IP's

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem a question regarding Docker, if I were you, I would setup a Nginx as a proxy/load balancer and pass traffic to the backend service, be it any service running on Docker or others

Also you can create Nginx using Docker

Next is how you assign the IP and find the port Nginx is listening to

Answer (score 0):

To be honestly, I don't know how to handle it with `--net=host`.

But, one possible solution is: not use `host network`, use `default bridge0's bridge network`. But you need to know the ports of your application used, and expose it by yourself. Then, when expose the ports, you can specify the ip.

Something like follows:

```
docker run -d -p 204.12.240.210:80:80 -p 204.12.240.210:8080:8080 disarmm/matrix
docker run -d -p 204.12.240.211:80:80 -p 204.12.240.211:8080:8080 disarmm/matrix
```

Then, you can see in host, you have two 80/8080 ports open on same host machine binding with different IP.

As mentioned above, the limit is: you have to know what ports you used exactly.

See [this](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#expose-incoming-ports) for format.